# Efficiency of 2NF databases vs. null-valued databases

Tags: database, hibernate

I'm structuring a few new tables in a previously-developed application and I've come across an issue with my database. Specifically, I have data that looks like this (the first column is a parent code and the rest are children, if that makes any sense):

```
abc-1  ab     NULL   NULL
abc-4  ab(1)  ab(3)  NULL
abe-2  ac(2)  ac(1)  ac                  **NOT NORMALIZED**
abe-3  ad(7)  NULL   NULL

(and so on...)
```

I *could* structure it like this instead:

```
abc-1  ab
abc-4  ab(1)
abc-4  ab(3)
abe-2  ac(2)                             **NORMALIZED**
abe-2  ac(1)
abe-3  ad(7)

(and so on...effectively disallowing all NULL values)
```

What I keep conceptually stumbling on, however, is which one of these is more effective. I'm working with an SQL server (Microsoft) and Java's Hibernate and JPA frameworks. Initially I thought I would go with the former option and just 'filter out' the NULL values in later code. A colleague suggested I do the latter and create multiple tables mapping to unique keys. I understand that would be the ideal way from a database standpoint, but I thought I'd ask the community if there were any efficiency reasons why I should avoid the former in favor of the latter.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
My tables have a many-to-many relationship, so I think that complicates things more than I'm probably realizing. As a more definitive example the table of the relationships looks like this:

```
abc-1   ab
abc-4   ab(1)
abc-4   ab(3)
abc-1   ab(1)

...etc...
```

So, you can see that in the 'parent' column `abc-1` may map to two different children and one child (`ab(1)` for instance) may map back to two different parents (`abc-4` and `abc-1`). Unless I'm completely mistaken this is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: So, you have a ManyToMany association between you `abc-x` entities and your `axxx` entities? The second way is the only way to model a ManyToMany with Hibernate. If the association is not a ManyToMany, then describe it, with a concrete example.

Comment: @JBNizet please see my update. It's a many-to-many relationship. I take it that my (original) second option is the only way to model this in Hibernate by what you've already stated. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes. Your first way of mapping doesn't look at all like a ManyToMany. It looks like 3 OneToOne.